# using fpdf : str_pad doesn't work with spaces, it works with other characters

Tags: php, string, fpdf

I am adding a pad to my string, to fill with spaces, but it doesn't work
the code is here

```
<?php 
    $string1 = "Product 1 ";
    $newString  = str_pad($string1,100);
    echo $newString."test";
    echo "<br>";
    $string2 = "Product 2222 ";
    echo str_pad($string2,100," ")."test";
    echo "<br>";
 ?>
```

the output is like this:

```
Product 1 test
Product 2222 test
```

Comment: Are you viewing this in a browser? Multiple consecutive spaces in HTML are compressed into one, unless you work around it with CSS/etc.

Comment: Don't output this to HTML, multiple spaces are displayed as one space in HTML. Or enclose your output with `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: Check [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/887c1fd7b97a0b109d33431bade6c9b3dd58340a)

Comment: I am using it  with fpdf

Answer (score 2):

You could try `$str = str_pad($string2,(100*strlen("&nbsp;")),"&nbsp;")."test";` instead.

`&nbsp;` renders to a non-breaking-space in html (and when writing to document with fpdf).

Please note this can only work with fpdf when you tell it to write all lines as html! And the encoding should be utf-8 probably

```
$fpdf->Write(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($str)));
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44b70ff6ac0938e1fac11c76e7df6bc32df563c1 I tried it didn't work

Comment: Sandbox prints the result in a textarea, which does not display the &nbsp; ... Please note that you should use `100*6` as length to prevent the entitie code from getting trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

When the output of the **PHP** is converted to **HTML**, all **the white spaces except the first are removed** and it is the default feature of HTML and web browsers. so the output will not be correct.
You have to use the " " instead of white space in the str_pad function. HTML don't ignore the " " and against each existance of it, HTML adds a white space to the string.